# Deploying laravel 5 on ubuntu , getting white page

Tags: php, git, ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5

I am trying to get my application online by following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04):

I am hosting with : www.ovh.com

I changed "sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/app/storage"
to "sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/storage"  as you should for laravel5

and when I pull my repo from github, and go to my website adress I get a white page.

I pulled it into /var/www/laravel

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You may need to post your errors in your error log.

Comment: I am pretty new to all of this, so how do I get my error logs?

Comment: I assume you do not have SSH access. And if you are pretty new to that maybe it is better to stay away from SSH for now. Try looking in your ovh dashboard, I read something about logs there: http://www.ovh.nl/shared-hosting/multilogs.xml

Comment: I just redid the whole guide again for the 10th time or something and now it is working, not sure what I was doing wrong as I did exactly the same thing.. Thx for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubtuntu you will find the error_log at /var/log/apache2 . This must give you information of what is happening and how to fix it.

If you have correct permissions then usually it has been related to some Laravel dependency missing.